# Correct package name of TYPO3 core in a composer.json

Tags: json, composer-php, typo3

If I add a composer.json to my TYPO3 extension, which package name of the core is correct?

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": ">=6.2.0",
},
```

or

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms": ">=6.2.0",
},
```

There exist different documentations: https://wiki.typo3.org/Composer or https://composer.typo3.org/. On packagist the name is typo3/cms.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at http://insight.helhum.io/post/155297666635/typo3-extension-dependencies-revisited which describes the solution.

In short: use `typo3/cms-core`.

Answer (score 3):

See http://insight.helhum.io/post/155297666635/typo3-extension-dependencies-revisited - basically, this boils down to one thing:

Do you wish to prevent users from running `composer install` after checking out your repository?

If you want to explicitly prevent this, use `typo3/cms-core`. If you don't, or don't care, and in particular if you want to use CI for unit testing, use `typo3/cms` instead.

Benefit of `typo3/cms` over `typo3/cms-core` is that `typo3/cms` is a proper package - `typo3/cms-core` is an alias which is marked as "replaced by" the real package.

But be aware that differences of opinions exist about this matter. The above recommendation is my personal preference with FluidTYPO3 since we heavily use a simple CI setup that works after running `composer install` on a checked out HEAD.

Comment: "and in particular if you want to use CI for unit testing, use typo3/cms instead" I disagree, **especially** when using CI for testing, I recommend `typo3/cms-core` because you most likely want to test against multiple TYPO3 versions anyway. Besides that, a dependency to `typo3/cms` means that your extension technically depends on every single TYPO3 core extensions, which most likely is wrong

Comment: That `typo3/cms-core` *currently* is not a package on Packagist, does not mean this will stay this way. So using adding a dependency to `typo3/cms-core` (and any additional core extension your extension depends on) is more appropriate in the long run

Answer (score 3):

In your **extension** you use

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms-core": ">=6.2.0",
},
```

In your root composer.json of your **project** you use

```
"require": {
    "typo3/cms": ">=6.2.0",
},
```

This is btw documented correctly on both sources you linked :)